# How to perform an action once nested fetch-es are complete?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

The code below fetches an array from an API, then for each element of this array, retrieves further data.

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
    r.data.forEach(x => {
      fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
          r.data.forEach(x => console.log(x.id))
        })
    })
  })
```

**I need to perform some action on the data once it is fully retrieved. How to do that?**

The problem is that this is a set of Promises which resolve asynchronously. `Promise.all()` could be used to gather all Promises and work from there - but their amount is not known upfront. In other words, I could use

```js
a = fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
b = fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
Promise.all([a, b]).then(x => console.log('all resolved here'))
```

but what is passed to `Promise.all()` is not known when the script starts.

Answer (score 2):

> ...but what is passed to Promise.all() is not known when the script starts.

That's okay, you can use `map` instead of `forEach` and then wait on the result:

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(r => r.json()).then(r =>
    Promise.all(r.data.map(x =>
      fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users') // (presumably there's some parameter here, you're not just repeating the same call...)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
          r.data.forEach(x => console.log(x.id))
        })
    ))
  );
```

The chain the above returns won't settle until all of the promises created in the `map` have resolved, or any of them has rejected.

Answer (score 2):

You can make array of promises using `Array.map`:

```
const allPromises = r.data.map(x => {
  return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/' + x)
    .then(r => r.json())
});

Promise.all(allPromises).then(data => console.log('All data is loaded', data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be the solution for, but it seems like something is wrong with your approach.

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
    return Promise.all(r.data.map(x => {
      return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
          r.data.forEach(x => console.log(x.id))
        })
      )
    })
  })
```

In other words you could use nested Promise.all and return it as a result of execution of inner code of your `then`s. And one important note, you should use `map` not `forEach` for iterative asynchronous calls.